# woocomerce plugin to send request upon payment/purchase

Tags: php, wordpress

ive written a plugin (its just a php file in  folder in the plugins folder) tht is  supposed to send some info to  flask app, but at the moment nothng is happening when i do a test order usin g a 100% coupon code, also hen i ctivte the plugin i get the error: The plugin generated 1 character of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “ headers already sent ” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.
what am i doing wrong

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:  woopostreq
Description: Custom actions for WooCommerce.
Version: 1.0
Author: callum
*/


add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'so_payment_complete' );
function so_payment_complete( $order_id ){      $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

$billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();
$billing_phone = $order->get_billing_phone();
$order_date = $order->get_date_paid();

$url = 'http://blanked out/woocommercepost'; // Add 'http://' to the URL

// Prepare the data for the request
$data = array(
    'orderid' => $order_id,
    'billingemail' => $billing_email,
    'billingphone' => $billing_phone,
    'orderdate' => $order_date
);

// Post the request
wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 45,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array(),
    'body' => $data // Pass data using 'body' parameter
));
}
```